# How can I calculate the dominant color of a TBitmap in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio

Is there a quick way to calculate the dominant color (the most common color) in a bitmap in Firemonkey?

Or is there an option in FMX to reduce the number of colors when using a color palette, e.g. as in Vcl.Imaging.GIFImg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented my own solution yet, which is not optimized for calculating fast results.

```
function GetDominanteColor(Bmp: TBitmap): TAlphaColor;
var
  BMPData: TBitmapData;
  x, y: integer;
  Col: TAlphaColor;
  Count: cardinal;
  Histogram: TDictionary<TAlphaColor, cardinal>;
begin
  result := TAlphaColors.Null;
  if Bmp.Width * Bmp.Height > 0 then
    if Bmp.Map(TMapAccess.Read, BMPData) then
    begin
      Histogram := TDictionary<TAlphaColor, cardinal>.Create;
      try
        // build histogram
        for x := 0 to Bmp.Width - 1 do
          for y := 0 to Bmp.Height - 1 do
          begin
            Col := BMPData.GetPixel(x, y);
            if Histogram.TryGetValue(Col, Count) then
              Histogram.Items[Col] := Count + 1
            else
              Histogram.Add(Col, 1);
          end;
        // search color with highest score
        Count := 0;
        for Col in Histogram.Keys do
        begin
          if Histogram.Items[Col] > Count then
          begin
            Count := Histogram.Items[Col];
            result := Col;
          end;
        end;
        {$IFDEF DEBUG}
        FMX.Types.Log.d('Dominante color %s from %d colors',
          [IntToHex(result, 8), x]);
        {$ENDIF}
      finally
        Histogram.Free;
      end;
      BMP.Unmap(BMPData);
    end;
end;
```

On an old CPU (i5-3360@2.8GHz) this function needs up to 200ms for a full HD image. Acceleration could be to limit the color space or to take not each pixel but to use a representative set of pixels.